# vba before save event change cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set the value of my cell R3 to 'RDC Mode' when the user hits save.

The value which has changed needs to be saved as the workbook is saving.

For some reason this code won't change my value.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Worksheets("Place Orders").Range("R3").Value = "RDC Mode"
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: what is _"The value which has changed"_?

Comment: @user3598756 cell R3 contains a data validation list with the following: Head Office Mode,RDC Mode. The user can manually set each value, but when they save the workbook the value needs to always be set back to RDC Mode

Comment: that code for me works. you may events disabled. in this case: 1) in VBE Immediate Window type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and press return. 2) check your other code for some `Application.EnableEvents = False` statement and be sure it _always_ reaches some subsequent `Application.EnableEvents = True` before ending

Answer (score 2):

You code works **if it is located in the proper place.**

[image]

It goes in the *ThisWorkbook* code area.